# Unable to extract .sh file

Tags: linux, extract

I am new to Linux and I am trying to install **MiniConda3** on an old 32bit machine running **Linux Mint19**. But I keep getting the following error:

```
Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86.sh: line 358:  2191 Illegal instruction 
(core dumped) "$PREFIX/pkgs/python-3.7.0-hc3d631a_0/bin/python" -E -s 
"$PREFIX"/pkgs/.install.py $INST_OPT --root-prefix="$PREFIX" --link-dist="$1"
```

Is this a permissions thing or a compatibility issue?

Thanks for any help provided

Comment: Do you have all the dependencies needed by the app? We really can't troubleshoot this issue as there is not enough information here. Plus, Stack Overflow is not really the place to ask about installing software. I would try the MiniConda help forums or mailing list.

Comment: "Illegal Instruction (core dumped)" is a pretty bad error. Something went wrong in that `.install.py` python file and went wrong big time. Definitely would bring this back to a forum dedicated to that product and ask there. It's almost definitely not a permission issue or really anything else that is going to be simple to diagnose.

Comment: Just to be certain, check your system requirements meet the [spec here](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/index.html#system-requirements). Namely: 400mb disk space, Python versions 2.7, 3.4, 3.5 or 3.6, [pycosat](https://pypi.org/project/pycosat/) and [PyYaml](https://pypi.org/project/PyYAML/) must be installed first. That could probably be done quickly with [pip](https://www.tecmint.com/install-pip-in-linux/).